# What is this before a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I am seeing a select that states `SELECT something.columnName FROM Table`. 
I'm just wondering what the "something" is used for?

Comment: Are you sure `something` is not a table name, or an Alias of a table?

Comment: It can be alias for tables or a complete another table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select from multiple tables in a single query then you can specify the table and column name you want to select. Example:

```
select table1.col1, table1,col2, table2.col5
from table1
join table2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

You can also specify alias names for tables or columns to make things shorter or if you join the same tables twice. Example:

```
select t1.col1 as A, t1.col2 as B, t2.col5 as C
from veryLongTableName1 t1
join veryLongTableName2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I had no time to type exactly this! XD

Answer (score 1):

That is either a table name or an alias for a table name.

When joining tables, you might need to specify which table a field should be fetched from. Example:

```
select TableA.Name, TableB.Name
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableB.id = TableA.id
```

Example with aliases:

```
select a.Name, b.Name
from TableA as a
inner join TableB as b on b.id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a alias to show form wich table the column comes. You need this if you `join` to tables wich have a colum with the same name.